# Extending class while retaining the name in java

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to extend a class in java while retaining the original name? if now can i add to that class extra functions(note this class is provided by the android sdk, its the view class)

Comment: This is not possible, but perhaps if you can describe what you want to do at a higher level then someone can suggest an alternative method for what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @goto10 for example i would like to add a function to the View class in android but i dont want to extend it and use a new class name.

Comment: I understand that much. But can you describe your goal in more general terms? "I want all views to be purple." "I want all views to pop up a message box that says 'hi' when I click on them." The specific technical solution you want isn't possible but there might be another way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: @goto10 i would like to edit the dispatchTouchEvent function in the view class so that i can log the event then pass it to be processed. The reason i dont want to extend the class is because i have alot of activities and changing all view classes to my new extended class doesnt make sense

Comment: A couple things - Activities aren't Views, so there's some confusion there. If you want to override the behavior of dispatchTouchEvent for Views there's no good way to do that. If you want to override it for Activities, then extending a base class that implements dispatchTouchEvent is *the* way to do it.

Comment: The fact that you may have multiple activities shouldn't be an obstacle to doing this. The only change you need to make to them is to add "extends <yourbaseclassname>" at the top of each. Most Android apps don't have more than 10-15 activities, but even for 100 activities this would just take a few minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, classes in Java are not "re-openable". An extension is a new class.

(With a caveat that through treachery you might be able to add bytecode, but nothing would be able to access it at compile-time.)

Comment: Agreed.  There is nothing in Java similar to Objective-C "categories".

Comment: @MikeG [This](http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/21549d6f3228eb50?pli=1) would seem to disagree. Either way, it depends when, and how, you want to add it. Like I said--wouldn't be available at compile time anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this only if it's in a different package. (That is, it can have the same simple name, but not the same qualified name.)

```
package com.me;

class Number extends java.lang.Number {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Just spent an hour resolving a totally unrelated issue and this answer put me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

When you extend a class in java, you do so by creating a new class with a new name.
ex:

```
public class MySpecialView extends View
```

The extended class is not modified.

Answer (score 0):

i assume you mean the fully qualified name (FQN = package + class name). so, no, you can´t, and you really shouldn´t. Thats the point of having a package name in the first place.

If you insist in doing it, however, you can create a new class with the same package and the same name, starting with the original source code (assuming you have it), and change whatever functionality you need. Depending on the classpath order (usually your source code has precedence over any included libraries, but you must make sure it is so) the classloader will pick your class instead of the original one. but this is more of a hack and i strongly suggest to avoid it unless you know exactly what you're doing, because you could end up with all sorts of unexpected behavior.